# Test "dynamic" page title in a view spec (Rails 4 + RSpec 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am currently following a tutorial but Rails and Rspec have evolved, especially for writing tests.

My goal is to test that when I visit the page "http://domain.fr**/users/1**" the page title follow the format : `"#{base_title} | #{@user.name}"` where base_title is constant.

Before, I saw it was possible to use render_views in controller specs but it is not the best way and it does not exist anymore in Rails 4/RSpec 3.

My last try is :

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe "users/show.html.erb", type: :view do
  it "Should finally render a correct title" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    assign(:user, user)
    render template: "users/show.html.erb", layout: "layouts/application.html.erb"
    expect(rendered).to have_selector("title", text: user.name)
  end
end
```

I use an helper for rendering in **application.html.erb** : `<title><%= title %></title>`

Here is the helper :

```rb
def title
  base_title = "Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails"
  @title.nil? ? base_title : "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
end
```

And the **show** method from **users_controller.rb** :

```rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = @user.name
end
```

I also added `resources :users` to my **routes.rb** file.

The above test fail because only the constant part of the title is rendered. Thus, I think **Users#show** is not called and @title not defined but I don't see how to achieve this.

Also my goal is to avoid calling assign() for each variable in my view as it can become problematic when you have a lot of variables to render.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the `title`:

```
assign(:user, user)
assign(:title, user.name)
```

Comment: But in case I have to render a lot of variables in my view, isn't there a way to automatically resolve my view's variables automatically ?
If I have a big view I need to call assign() for each variable ?

Comment: Yes. Ideally you don't want too many instance variables in a controller action. Maybe wrap those into a single object

Comment: Ok I understand the logic. Thank you very much !